# Relative linking <img> tag src

Tags: html, image, src

I have an HTML page located in `localhost/about/` and an image located in `localhost/images.` In my HTML, I have an `img` tag like this:

```
img src="../images/logo.png"
```

When I view this page in a browser, the logo image is shown for a second and the `alt` text appears. Inspecting the image info, the page in the src is changed to `"localhost/about/images/logo.png".`

**Edit:** I am displaying the image like this.

```
 <!-- header-left start -->
 <!-- ================ -->
 <div class="header-left">
     <div class="logo">
         <a href="../"><img id="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Alt Text" width="196" height="60"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- header-left end -->
```

**Folder Structure:**
[image: The image 'logo.png' is in the root 'dir' of the folder 'images']

Is the anything I am doing wrong with this relative path source?

Comment: Please share the code .. and folder setup path too if possible.. Is this in developing environment or just static html?

Comment: Not with this relative path no. There might be something else messing up with the documentURI. This *one second* thing is really weird. Are you somehow redirected ? Do you have any script running on this page ? Try to disable all and reenable until you found which one causes this. If it still occurs without scripts, try to disable all your browser's extensions. If it still occurs, check your server configs.

Comment: try ~/images/logo.png

Comment: @YogeshSharma — Do you have some reason to believe the OP is using some server side processing that will resolve the `~` character?

Comment: @Quentin the URL which given ../images will always take page URL also with the hostname, in this case we only need to add hostname and I think ~ this is the perfect symbol to add only hostname

Comment: @YogeshSharma — No. In a URL `~` is just a character that can appear in a path. It does not "add a hostname" (unless some server side process is involved, I think it might have special meaning in ASP.NET)

Comment: @Kaiido — Ah, missed that bit when I read the question.

Comment: Could you post the result of executing `document.baseURI` in the Javascript console on the page?

Comment: @QuentinI Yes in inspect element will not show any host-name dynamically it will add the hostname once we will open that link into new window.

Comment: @YogeshSharma — The URL will be resolved from a relative to absolute URL whenever it needs to be resolved (including when the browser tries to load the image). The absolute URL will be shown in the address bar if you navigate to it. This has *nothing to do with the `~` character*.

Comment: @Fanuel — As Kaiido points out, the image is loading successfully and then being unloaded. I can't think of any reason for this other than JavaScript changing the image in the page. The problem isn't to do with the URL in the HTML source. It is elsewhere in some code you haven't included in the question.

Comment: As a temp solution, I have created an `images` folder in each folder and moved the relevant images into the respective folders. Then I changed the `src` to the local images folder. Although this involves some duplication of images, it works, at least until I find the problem in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the `baseURI` property of the `document` javascript object. [As defined by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI):

> The base URL is used to resolve relative URLs when the browser needs to obtain an absolute URL, for example when processing the HTML  element's src attribute or XML xlink:href attribute.

Check the base URL value by entering the following in the Javascript Console:

```
console.log(document.baseURI);
```